# User listing messed up sometimes on IE8

Tags: bug, status-completed, internet-explorer

This is a repost from [UI Meta](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/user-listing-messed-up-sometimes-on-ie8), but it affects the SO site, the meta SO site and the ui.stackexchange.com site as well:

Not sure if this is the right forum, but there's an issue with the user listing page on IE8 where some of the users get squished together:
[image: ui.stackexchange user listing bug]

[image: stackoverflow user listing bug]

Comment: Long standing bug.  I know that I've reported it before, but I can't find a reference.  Possibly it was on the original UserVoice site.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't relevant anymore, since the user list page has since been overhauled, but just for the record, we did indeed put a workaround for this in place. I'll let the code speak for itself:

```
@* The following pretty useless rule is solely for the eigth iteration
   of a certain browser from Redmond. Forcing some content between the
   users (even if invisible) seems to stop a bug randomly overlapping
   two user infos (see e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39353). *@
    .user-info:after
    {
        content:'.';
        height:0;
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. My avatar is too awesome to be displayed in IE...

Comment: No one appreciates humor anymore...

Comment: I chuckled a bit.

Comment: lol.. maybe this should have been a comment instead of an answer (:

Comment: @Ryan It *could* have been the answer to why you are missing an avatar..

Comment: @Ryan The distinction is pretty much non-existent on meta

Answer (score -3):

This is a bug in IE8, not us.

Comment: ..............!